# Meteor.js packages download every time on file change

Tags: meteor

I'm developing a little app with meteor.js
After editing a file loaded by server, it does the server restart before the livereload;
this restart takes a long time, and everytime in the console it says "downloading packages";

I can't understand what it needs to download every time and if there is a way to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue they're working on. You can follow the progress at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2846